# Работа с MainWindow WPF из стороннего класса

Tags: c#, wpf

В основном окне WPF находится TabControl и для каждой вкладки я хотел создать классы для обработки происходящего в ней. Но столкнулся с проблемой что не могу из этого класса получить доступ к элементам управления основной формы, вызову MessageBox и т.д. Подскажите возможно ли это или я все неправильно делаю.

Comment: В этом случае лучше всего использовать паттерн Mvvm. Для этого есть разные библиотеки, одна из лучших MvvmCross или Caliburn.Micro. Фишка в том, что изменяя модели в классе-вьюмодели  - будет меняться UI в представлении

Comment: и не плохо было бы код увидеть